# Strange error related to theorem name (XeTeX)

Tags: errors, theorems

Trying to have a theorem with `[name=Dominio e codominio dell'operatore $D^{\vct{q}}$,label=thm:oss:DomCodomDq]` gives the following error:

[image: The error on the TeXShop console]

The error is given by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,thmtools}  
\newtheorem{oss}{Osservazione}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{oss}[name=Dominio e codominio dell'operatore $D^{\overrightarrow{q}}$,label=thm:oss:DomCodomDq]  
\end{oss}  
\end{document}
```

where `\vct` has been replaced by its primitive name `\overrightarrow`. The error is apparently related to `\vct`, as removing that removes the error. What does that mean and how do I solve it?

Comment: Without knowing how you defined `\vct`, how can we tell something sensible?

Comment: @egreg but the error occurs with `\overrightarrow` too.

Comment: As a quick work around use `...$D^{\vec{q}}$...` to avoid the error.

Comment: Fragile command in a moving argument: `\protect\overrightarrow` when used in `name=` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a dummy:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,thmtools}  
\newtheorem{oss}{Osservazione}  
\begin{document}  
\def\dummy{$D^{\overrightarrow{q}}$}
\begin{oss}[name=Dominio e codominio dell'operatore \protect\dummy,label=thm:oss:DomCodomDq]  
\end{oss}  
\end{document}
```

or use:

```
$D^{\protect\overrightarrow{q}}
```

Comment: The `\dummy` thing, I think, goes against the What You See Is What You Mean principle, so I prefer the direct thing. In any case @egreg, what exactly _does_ this `\protect` command do?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands